# Java Modal Dialog from main command line

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Can I create a Jframe dialog from a java command line program and wait for a return before continue executing of the main program?

The below code does not work but it's what I have in mind.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
     Dialog dl = new DialogGui();
     dl.setVisable(true);
     while(dl.isVisiabl(){
         //wait....
     }
 }
```

A plus would be if it was able to return data from the Jframe..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `JFrame`, use a `JDialog`.

There is a pre-packaged dialog factory you are looking for: [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).  Its dialogs are both modal and block until the method returns.  For example, a confirmation dialog:

```
if ( JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "this is a message",
                    "this is a title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE ) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
{
    // do something since the user selected yes
}
```

The dialogs are reasonably customizable, see the docs.